# Clojure code for finding prime numbers

Tags: primes, clojure

This is my Clojure code for finding prime numbers.

Note: this is an advanced version which starts eliminating from `i*i` with step `i`, instead of filtering all list against `mod i == 0` [(Sieve of Eratosthenes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

It has better asymptotic runtime: `O(n log log n)` instead of `O(n log n)` in typical examples of finding primes in Clojure.

What can be done better? Do I use some slow constructions? Can I make it more concise? Gain more performance? Format it better?

```
(defn primes [n]
  (let [mark (fn [i di v]
               (if (<= i (count v))
                 (recur (+ i di) di (assoc v (dec i) di))
                 v))
        step (fn [i ps v]
               (if (<= i (count v))
                 (if (= (v (dec i)) 1)
                   (recur (inc i) (conj ps i) (mark (* i i) i v))
                   (recur (inc i) ps v))
                 ps))]
(->> (repeat 1) (take n) vec (step 2 []))))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (primes 50)))
```

Comment: it will be `n log (log n)` only if `(assoc v (dec i) di)` is O(1).

Answer (score 2):

*(non-Clojure-specific)* Gain performance, sure. Use packed array of odds, where index `i` represents value `2i+1`. Then you don't have to deal with evens, which are all non-prime a priori (except the 2 of course). Then you can increment by `2*p` for a prime `p` to find its odd multiples twice faster.

For a non-marked index `i`, the prime `p` is `p = 2*i+1`, its square is `p*p = (2i+1)(2i+1) = 4i^2 + 4i + 1` and *its* index is `(p*p-1)/2 = 2i^2 + 2i = 2i(i+1) = (p-1)(i+1)`. For the value increment of `2*p`, the index increment on 2x-packed array is `di = p = 2i+1`.

Answer (score 1):

I've played around with your code to try to understand it, frankly. After a long sequence of changes, I ended up with the following:

```
(defn primes [n]
  (let [mark (fn [i di v]
               (reduce
                 (fn [w i] (assoc w i di))
                 v
                 (range i (count v) di)))
        [answer &_] (reduce
                      (fn [[ps v :as both] i]
                        (if (= (v i) 1)
                          [(conj ps i) (mark (* i i) i v)]
                          both))
                      (let [init-v (->> (repeat 1) (take n) (vec))]
                        [[] init-v])
                      (range 2 n))]
    answer))
```

- I've got rid of the `dec`s in all the accesses to the vector `v`.
- I've captured the `recur`s, in the `mark` and `step` functions,
  in `reduce`s.
- Since the `step` function is no longer recursive, I've unwrapped it
  into its one call.

The new `mark` function is a little faster. But the `step` equivalent is going to be slower, since it generates a new pair-vector for every prime.

The main problem here is space - your vector `v` is the size of your candidate range of numbers. I've come across a cute algorithm that gets round this, though at some cost in speed, spent on laziness.